# Rotating a node with a joystick

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I made a simple spritekit game where a boat moves around when you move a joystick. The joystick works great for moving the boat and the angle of the boat matches the angle that the joystick is pressed in. However, when I want to do a complete 180 degree turn or any other major turn with the joystick, the boat turns completely around with no delay. However, with my game I want to make it so to turn the boat I want it to go around in a circle, almost as if it is turning around an invisible node. I don't want it to turn around instantly, I want it to circle around to turn like a real boat [like this.](http://www.boatus.com/Assets/www.boatus.com/magazines/boatus/2014/october/img/turn-radius-boat.gif)

Code:

```
 //MARK: Handlers begin
    moveAnalogStick.beginHandler = { [unowned self] in


        guard self.appleNode != nil else {
            return
        }

    }



    moveAnalogStick.trackingHandler = { [unowned self] jData in
        self.appleNode?.zRotation = jData.angular

        guard let aN = self.appleNode else {
            return
        }

        aN.position = CGPoint(x: aN.position.x + (jData.velocity.x * 0.12), y: aN.position.y + (jData.velocity.y * 0.12))
    }

    moveAnalogStick.stopHandler =  { [unowned self] in

        guard self.appleNode != nil else {
            return
        }

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I cant see where you set the boast’s rotation, but if you set it directly, try changing that to an `SKAction.rotate(toAngle:duration:)` with a suitable duration.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417668-rotate

Comment: Issue is a little more complex then just changing the rotation angle.  You need to think about the turning radius the boat has, and alter the velocity to handle the rotation over time.

Comment: E.G.  your boat is traveling 0 degrees and has a turning radius of 10 degrees,  it would take 18 clicks before he hits 180 degrees.  So what you need to do is do `min(joystickAngle - boatAngle, boatTurningAngle)` to determine how much change you need to apply to the boats angle any given frame